# Incorrect output from resample function converting OHLC minute data to daily OHLC data

Tags: python, time-series

I am getting incorrect data using the `resample` function to convert minute data into daily data. After a careful examination of the output, I have discovered that the process is outputting the open of the 16:00 bar for the DAILY OPEN.  Furthermore, it is outputting the close of the 9:31 bar as the DAILY CLOSE.

Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pylab import mpl, plt
plt.style.use('seaborn')
mpl.rcParams['font.family'] = 'serif'
%matplotlib inline
import cufflinks as cf

df = pd.read_csv('ES#CMin_Pit.csv', index_col='Date', parse_dates=['Date'])

df.tail()

Time    Inc Vol Volume  Open    High    Low Close
Date                            
2005-09-07  09:34:00    2309.0  39145.0 1150.75 1151.00 1150.50 1150.75
2005-09-07  09:33:00    1803.0  36836.0 1150.75 1150.75 1150.25 1150.50
2005-09-07  09:32:00    972.0   35033.0 1150.75 1150.75 1150.50 1150.75
2005-09-07  09:31:00    1440.0  34061.0 1150.75 1151.00 1150.50 1150.50
NaT NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN

conversion = {'Open' : 'first', 'High' : 'max', 'Low' : 'min', 'Close' : 'last', 'Volume' : 'sum'}

data_day =  df.resample('D').apply(conversion)

data_day.tail(5)

Open    High    Low Close   Volume
Date                    
2018-05-20  NaN NaN NaN NaN 0.0
2018-05-21  2732.50 2739.25 2725.25 2730.50 210297692.0
2018-05-22  2726.00 2741.75 2721.50 2738.25 179224835.0
2018-05-23  2731.75 2732.75 2708.50 2710.50 292305588.0
2018-05-24  2726.00 2730.50 2705.75 2725.00 312575571.0
```

I suspect that the problem is establishing the "conversion" dictionary, however, I have seen this method uses more than once in my research.  Any suggestions to specify the appropriate bar to pull the daily open and close values from?  Namely, to use the "first," of 9:31 minute bar instead of the 16:00 bar for the DAILY OPEN price.  Additionally to use the "last" of the 16:00 bar instead of the 9:31 bar for the DAILY CLOSE price?  Thanks LL

Answer (score 0):

The possible problem can be that your time series data is not ordered in a time increasing order. 
Try:
data_day = df.groupby(df.Date).ohlc()

Answer (score 0):

I think you just mixed up `groupby` and `resample` in your mind, because you want to *select* certain values of a day (the first, the last, the max etc.) what can be done by grouping. But resample *recalculates* your data by interpolating and mean to just one single value per day to redraw the characteristic over time with different samples as close as possible to the original.

In short: just replace `resample` by `groupby`.